# Web Crawling Form Help Needed

Tags: web-development, web-applications, webforms, web-scraping

If I have a form built on my website. How can I get that form 1 to plugin results into another websites form 2 and extract information to display on my website?

For example, if I wanted to create a form like cartagz.com for registration fees on my website romarinsurance.com so that my customers can see their Registration fees and pay via my website.

Would I need to use some sort of webcrawl software to pull such information and display it.

My guess is that cartagz.com is pulling information from https://www.dmv.ca.gov/wasapp/vrir/start.do?localeName=en

Dmv.ca.gov does not have api available.

Answer (score 0):

Many governmental websites provide their data through open data. For California, there is [a website](https://data.ca.gov/) which indexes what data is available.

If you need to rely on third-party data, you should:

- Either use a public API, if one is available,
- Or pay to be able to use a private API,
- Or contact the owner of the website to ask how should you access the data (either for free or by paying a license).

Any unauthorized crawling could get you into trouble:

- The interface of the website (including the URIs of the pages, the overall structure, etc.) can change without prior notice. You'll find that by discovering that your website doesn't work any longer.
- You may simply be blocked. If website usage is monitored, it is very simple to see such crawlers, and relatively easy to ban them. Most websites don't welcome such usage of their resources.
- If you were violating the license, you may also find yourself being sued and paying important fines. This is probably what will happen if you use governmental data without authorization.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I spoke to Government dmv officials and they mentioned that there is no api. I spoke to authorized DMV third party partners and they stated likewise. I am a authorized licensed DMV business partner myself and when they tell me theirs no api I can use than I'm not sure how cartagz.com is doing it because we hold the same license.     I have access to a paided DMV portal which allows me to process DMV transactions (renewals,duplicate stickers, transfer of ownership) for my customers. The company  provides us data to process transactions.

Comment: The issue is that https://www.dmv.ca.gov/wasapp/vrir/start.do?localeName=en Dmv.ca.gov is a public link feed public data.  While my third party DMV portal does give me access I am the only one authorized who can access it with my username and password.  Cartagz.com is using a crawler to input license number and extract fee amounts to display on their website then once their customer pays via a payment gateway cartagz.com will manually process transaction through their authorized dmv portal.